# Unable to link mat.h file on Mac

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm having issues linking the mat.h file from Matlab to my c++ file.

My portion where I'm including the directory for the .h file within my Makefile is here:

```
set(MAT_ROOTDIR "/Applications/MATLAB_R2021a.app/extern/include")
target_include_directories(onnxruntime_test PRIVATE ${MAT_ROOTDIR})
```

I simply #include <mat.h> within my cpp file, but I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_matClose_800", referenced from:
      matread(char const*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in model_explorer.cpp.o
  "_matGetVariable_800", referenced from:
      matread(char const*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in model_explorer.cpp.o
  "_matOpen_800", referenced from:
      matread(char const*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in model_explorer.cpp.o
  "_mxDestroyArray_800", referenced from:
      matread(char const*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in model_explorer.cpp.o
  "_mxGetNumberOfElements_800", referenced from:
      matread(char const*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in model_explorer.cpp.o
  "_mxGetPr_800", referenced from:
      matread(char const*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in model_explorer.cpp.o
  "_mxIsDouble_800", referenced from:
      matread(char const*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in model_explorer.cpp.o
  "_mxIsEmpty_800", referenced from:
      matread(char const*, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >&) in model_explorer.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am pretty sure it is finding the right .h file but I'm not sure why I'm still getting undefined symbols. Is there another thing I should be linking as well? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am working on a Mac OS.

Comment: Don't link the .h files. Include them. Somewhere else there will be a folder of library files you need to link in order to get the definitions of the stuff declared in the headers. Point the build tool at this folder and specify which libraries in that folder are needed.

Comment: Please read [mre]. We have no idea what you are doing in your CMake script, so cannot tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I was able to link the libraries and its to working

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you don't know what .h files are.

You probably need a -l argument when you link so it links the library.

The errors you're getting are not due to a failure to find the include file. They're due to an error finding compiled code -- which is probably in a library.

You can simulate yourself like this:

```
void foo();

int main(int, char **) {
    foo();
}
```

Compile that, and you'll get a similar error to the errors you listed -- because we don't have the code for `foo()` anywhere, and we haven't linked against a library that has it, either.